# Read file and find all occurrences and generate hash for the content between the occurrences

Tags: awk, grep, large-files, hashsum

I have a file like this :

```
1   Record|1111|ABC
2   text in between for record 1
3   text in between for record 1
4   Record|2222|XYZ
5   text in between for record 2    
6   Record|3333|XYZ
7   text in between for record 3
8   .
```

I want to read this file and generate something like

```
<Record_number> | <start line> | <number of lines> | md5sum(content)
```

That is:

```
1111|1|2|md5sum(Record|1111|ABC\ntext in between for record 1\ntext in between for record 1)
2222|4|1|md5sum(Record|2222|XYZ\ntext in between for record 2\n)
```

etc.

Currently, I am doing this using a two step process:

**Step 1:**

```
grep -n -C 0 "Record|" ../test.txt | awk -F[':|'] '{print $3"|"$1}'
```

will create

```
1111|1
2222|4
3333|6
```

**Step 2:**
Read this file line by line and generate md5sum and number of lines through script.

The issue it this two step processing is taking more processing time and the file size is huge (~4GB).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: is the file really has a line number?

Comment: No. It doesnt have. I gave it for understanding..

Comment: it's a tough job. did you wanna python solution?

Comment: Perl or unix is i am mainly looking for.

Comment: python is preinstalled on most of the linux distributions. I don't know what's wrong with the dangerous but user friendly python language.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : you can post your python solution as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Costas' answer.

1) Create a file parse.awk, with the following content :

```
/^Record/ {
  if (s>0) {
    printf ("%s|%s|", r,l)
    system("echo '"line"' | md5sum - | awk '{print $1}' ");
  }
  s=1;
  r=$2;
  c=1;
  l=NR;
  line="$0";
}
!/^Record/ {
  line=line"\n""$0";
  c+=1
}
END {
  printf ("%s|%s|", r,l)
  system("echo '"line"' | md5sum - | awk '{print $1}' ");
}
```

See Costas' explanations.
This script just do
`printf` the start of the resulting line (rather than print, that puts a newline)
`system(echo $line | md5sum)` to print the md5 - and a newline

2) Run `awk -F"|" -f parse.awk myfile`

3) Enjoy the result :

```
1111|1|cb36533781d8dd00011a85b0db9b87b3
2222|4|521331bb249e8a668afa2199fa8d289a
3333|6|6c2564464187094e9db3159d26ade2a5
```

Comment: line=line"§"$0; ? 
is "§" equivalent to "\n"

Comment: Sorry, there should be "\n" rather than § (I used § for testing purposes). Corrected

Comment: This fails if we have Record in any form in in between lines. Eg : "text in between for record 2(Record)"

Comment: Corrected the above issues by adding ^

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it can be

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '
function md5(lines){
  func="printf \"%s\" \""lines"\"|md5sum|cut -f1 -d\ " ;
  func | getline v;
  return v
}
/Record/{
  if(s>0)
    print r,l,c,md5(line);
  s=1;
  r=$2;
  c=1;
  l=NR;
  line=$0
}
!/Record/{
  line=line"\n"$0;
  c+=1
}
END{
  print r,l,c,md5(line);
}' file
```

Briefly code explanation:

1. Change field separators (input and output) to `|`
2. Assign `md5` function (thanks to [Pierre-Olivier Vares](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/79028/pierre-olivier-vares) for idea) to calculate md5sum for apropriate input lines. (may be there is better way to do it - you are welcome to comment)
3. For lines which have `Record` word put necessary fields into variables and break counters to 1 and prints previous formatted line starting from 2nd occurence of `Record` word (for 2nd prints 1st, for 3rd prints 2nd and so on).
4. For lines which have not `Record` word just add oneself to `line` variable and add 1 to counter `c`
5. When finish prints the last formatted line (because last line is stored in memory and should be printed when will meet next `Record` word but have met end of file)

Comment: Can you explain the code ? :-)

I am very new to unix.